# mysql where in array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Hi I have the following mysql query which breaks when I try to add the WHERE clause using an array. I think its in the right order but not sure if I'm wrong with the notation or something here. I am able to verify that $company_type does have data and is an array, but the SQL statement returns no results when I can verify that there are.

Thanks

```
"SELECT *,
         ( 6371 * acos( 
     cos(radians($lat)) * cos(radians(l.location_latitude)) * 
        cos(radians(l.location_longitude) - radians($lng)) + 
     sin(radians($lat)) * sin(radians(l.location_latitude)) 
    ) ) AS distance 
            FROM
        company c
            INNER JOIN
        bcompanytocompany bc
            ON c.company_id=bc.company_id
            INNER JOIN
        lcompany_types ct
            ON bc.company_type_id=ct.company_type_id
            INNER JOIN
        bcompanytolocations bcl
            ON c.company_id = bcl.company_id
            INNER JOIN
        address a
            ON bcl.address_id = a.address_id
            INNER JOIN
        location l
            ON a.address_location_id = l.location_id
            INNER JOIN
        postal_codes po
            ON a.address_postal_id = po.postal_id
            INNER JOIN
        cities ci
            ON po.city_id = ci.city_id
            INNER JOIN
        lprovinces pr
            ON ci.province_id = pr.province_id
        WHERE company_type_name 
            IN (".implode(',',$company_type).")
        HAVING distance < $setdistance
        ORDER BY distance
        LIMIT 30"
```

Comment: What type are the values in `$company_type`? Strings? Integers?

Comment: $company_type strings

Answer (score 1):

Since `$company_type` contains values that are strings you will need to wrap them in quotes if you wish to use `IN()`:

```
WHERE company_type_name 
        IN ('".implode("','",$company_type)."')
-- IN('string1','string2')
```

You can also use `FIND_IN_SET()` which is one string containing values separated by commas:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(company_type_name, '".implode(',',$company_type)."')
-- FIND_IN_SET(company_type_name, 'string1,string2')
```

Answer (score 1):

As I believe `company_type_name` holds strings, you are missing `'` for the strings. You're getting something like this:

```
IN (name1, name2, [...])
```

Instead of

```
IN ('name1', 'name2', [...])
```

Just fix your PHP `implode()` to add the string characters:

```
WHERE company_type_name 
        IN ('".implode("','",$company_type)."')
```